# I have written a program in java to read data from MS excel sheet but it is showing that (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
  public class Excel {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
      try {
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:/one"));
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
          HSSFRow next = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
          System.out.println("\n");
          Iterator cells = next.cellIterator();
          while (cells.hasNext()) {
            HSSFCell next2 = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
            if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == next2.getCellType()) {
              System.out.println(next2.getNumericCellValue() + "");
            } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == next2.getCellType()) {
              System.out.println(next2.getStringCellValue());
            } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN == next2.getCellType()) {
              System.out.println(next2.getBooleanCellValue() + "");
            } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK == next2.getCellType()) {
              System.out.println("BLANK           ");
            } else {
              System.out.println("unknown cell type");
            }

          }
        }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not given the file extension in your code for your file "D:/one" is it an xls ot xlsx or csv .

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:/one"));
```

...should be something like:

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:/folder/filename.xls"));
```

...depending on your file location and extension of course.

As an aside, I highly recommend [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) and [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html) by Lars Vogel.